# Struggling to clean a data set - wishing to include only lines where initial element begins with date/time

Tags: list-manipulation

```
testlist = {{"0000/01/01 01:00:30", 750, 94, 96, 105, 1018.08`, 0.038`, 0.022`, -1.023`},
            {"0000/01/01 01:00:31", 0, 94, 96, 88, 1018.1`, 0.037`, 0.024`, -1.019`},
            {"bad data set"}};
```

(* Need code here! *)

```
dataCol3 = Part[testlist , All, 3]
{94, 94} (* desired output! *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a test that uses `DateString` to read the date elements in the first element of a list:

```
test = (DateString[#[[1]],
        {"Year", "Month", "Day", "Hour", "Minute", "Second"}] //
         ToExpression // IntegerQ // Quiet) &;
test /@ testlist

(*  {True, True, False}  *)
```

`test` can be applied like this

```
Part[Pick[#, test /@ #], All, 3] &  @  testlist

(*   {94, 94}   *)
```

**Edit:**

A better way to apply `test` is like this

```
Cases[testlist, z_?test :> z[[3]]]

(*   {94, 94}   *)
```

Answer (score 2):

If all the dates start with "0000".

```
testlist // Select[StringMatchQ[First@#, "0000*"] &] // Part[#, All, 3] &
(* {94, 94} *)
```

Comment: May be a date like 2020/02/04

Comment: What date does "0000/01/01" represent?

Comment: a clock that was not set

Answer (score 2):

```
Cases[testlist, {_String?(StringStartsQ["0000"]), _, a_, ___} :> a]
```

> {94, 94}

Also

```
#[[Flatten[Position[#[[All, 1]], _String?(StringStartsQ["0000"])]], 3]] & @ testlist
```

> {94, 94}